# Is it possible to use the same parameter scoping from form_for, except from an AJAX call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axios

I'm submitting some data to my rails backend via an AJAX call (axios specifically).

My AJAX request looks something like this:

```
    Axios({
        url: "/terms/" + event.target.term_id.value,
        method: "put",
        data: {
            "term[en_text]": event.target["term[en_text]"].value,
            "term[de_text]": event.target["term[de_text]"].value,
            "term[jp_text]": event.target["term[jp_text]"].value
        },
        headers: {
            "Authorization": token
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
```

It looks as though the backend doesn't do the same kind of scoping it would do if I had submitted this via `form_for`:

```
  Parameters: {"term[en_text]"=>"Dates", "term[de_text]"=>"Datteln", "term[jp_text]"=>"foobars", "id"=>"1", "term"=>{}}
```

What the heck happened? As you can see from looking at the parameters received, none of them end up in `"term" => {}`

Comment: did you try to send a json as data value? 
`term: { en_text: event.target["term[en_text]"].value, de_text: event.target["term[de_text]"].value, jp_text: event.target["term[jp_text]"].value }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: {
  "term[en_text]": event.target["term[en_text]"].value,
  "term[de_text]": event.target["term[de_text]"].value,
  "term[jp_text]": event.target["term[jp_text]"].value
},
```

Would be correct if you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as its a simple key/value format and rack parses parameters with brackets into hashes (and arrays) when parsing form data (or query strings).

However if you are passing `application/json` you need to pass an actual JSON object instead:

```
data: {
  term: {
    en_text: event.target["term[en_text]"].value,
    de_text: event.target["term[de_text]"].value,
    jp_text: event.target["term[jp_text]"].value
  }
}
```

A JSON parser will not expand the keys, and there really is no need for that as JSON can actually express objects and arrays without the hackyness involved with form data.